# error in melpa installation of ac-rtags

Tags: package-repositories, rtags

When I install ac-rtags from melpa (M-x list-package) I have this error :

```
ac-rtags.el:33:11: Warning: Package cl is deprecated
ac-rtags.el:33:2: Error: Eager macro-expansion failure: (wrong-number-of-arguments (3 . 4) 2)
```

I tried to change my emacs version, but no difference.

In my init.el, concerning MELPA, I just have :

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
```

Comment: Is it only this package that causes problems? Have you tried to install other packages? What happens if you `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`? Do you get a backtrace? If so, add it to your question. Have you tried starting with `emacs -q` and doing the `add-to-list` above manually in your `*scratch*` buffer? If that works, your init file is at fault.